# hello world fails on gcc 5.3.0 /bin/ld: invalid option -- 'p'

Tags: c++, c, gcc

A basic question in getting my ec2 AMI complier set up correctly.

I have complied gcc 5.3.0 and have the following output

```
which g++
/home/mybin/bin/g++

g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/tmp/gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/mybin/ --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)

gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/tmp/gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/mybin/ --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

however when I try a hello world `/home/myuser/test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with `gcc /home/myuser/test.c -o test`

it returns

```
/home/mybin/bin/ld: invalid option -- 'p'
Try `ld --help' or `ld --usage' for more information.
```

thanks to @Ismael for the pointer, I have also run `gcc /home/myuser/test.c -o test` but could not find an obvious reference to `--p`

```
gcc -v /home/_cbs/hhvm/test.c -o test
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/tmp/gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/mybin/ --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/cc1 -quiet -v /home/_cbs/hhvm/test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o /home/tmp/ccRpAYPt.s
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /home/mybin/include
 /home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: b4408eaf5114d6109f8b7d1dd0485d10
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /home/tmp/ccW4b2Db.o /home/tmp/ccRpAYPt.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.52.0.1 (x86_64-amazon-linux) using BFD version version 2.23.52.0.1-55.65.amzn1 20130226
COMPILER_PATH=/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/:/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/:/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/:/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/:/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/:/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/collect2 -plugin /home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/home/mybin/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/home/tmp/ccQFq8sT.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test /usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crti.o /home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/crtbegin.o -L/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0 -L/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../.. /home/tmp/ccW4b2Db.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crtn.o
/home/mybin/bin/ld: invalid option -- 'p'
Try `ld --help' or `ld --usage' for more information.
collect2: error: ld returned 64 exit status
```

any pointers to what I have got wrong in my configuration?

thx Art.

Comment: Why is there a C file in /home/ on your system? Or do you mean /home/Username/test.c?

Comment: Have you tried updating/recompiling `ld` too ?

Comment: Gcc has a -v option which shows how it is invoking other commands.

Comment: @Ismael, update with gcc -v, looks same as g++ -v, no sign of the -- 'p' option I can see

Comment: @Rolbrok, No i have not recompiled it, where do I find the source repositories? I looked under `https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/` but I cant work out if this is the correct repository??

Comment: [git repository](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git), and a [guide](https://sourceware.org/binutils/binutils-porting-guide.txt) that could help.

Comment: You should compile with the -v flag, ie gcc -v /home/myuser/test.c -o test

Comment: what happens if you first make the object with gcc -c and then link?

Answer (score -1):

I thought this error occured because of external source error, not internal source error.

In my  experience, 
Using 3ways to fix.

Way1.
Reinstall visual studio

Way2.
1.Copy the source.
2. delete current project.
3.make new project and paste that source.

Way3.
Using xcode in mac os.